# Which actions in Drupal needs clearing the cache?

Tags: hooks, caching

I'm a newbie in Drupal. I usually use the clear cache function from Devel module for each changes(sometime I use `drush` command line tool) like: modify CSS, create/change blocks, change permissions, create new content type, create new web form, change template files... and clearing the cache costs a lot of time on my local environment (I've just 1GB of RAM).
So can anyone show me which actions in Drupal that we need to clear cache.

Comment: In general, if you used the UI to make the change, you don't need to clear cache. If you changed source files (such as CSS stylesheets, you do.) That'll cover 95% of cases.

Comment: Thanks @AlfredArmstrong: for the permission changing does clear cache affect instead of using rebuild permissions

Comment: When you say "rebuild permissions" are you referring rebuilding node access permissions? You don't normally need to do that unless you have a content access module installed, and in any case changing the permissions associated with roles won't require it, as it's essentially a different layer of access control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### REQUIRED

1. When you implement hooks (not all): like `hook_menu`, `hook_init`, `hook_block_info`, `hook_block_view`, `hook_theme` and so on.
2. If you have checked JS/CSS aggregation and you change your these files.
3. When you implement template functions in your `template.php` file (not modifications of existing functions).
4. When you override template files of core and contrib modules.
5. Changes of `hook_menu` and `.info` files.
   ...

#### NOT REQUIRED

1. Modifications of existing template functions.
2. Creating users, contents, content types, webforms, etc.
3. Changes of existing template files, permissions, etc.
4. Changes of js/css when aggregation is off.

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Strategy is quite easy - clear it when you changed something in code or database.

Below some popular cases (based on my experience):

- you added new content and need to update cached pages, views or blocks (for example you enables cache for anonymous users)
- you changed JS or CSS files and you have enabled aggregation
- you installed new modules (in this case need to run update.php)
- you did modifications in existing module which require update cache. For instance added menu item or implemented some hooks.
- you did changes in theme files